# Prevent display carriers before login / register

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am using quick order (opc) mode in my shop. The problem is that there are visible delivery options before customer create account or save address. I would like to hide this section, as it is done with payment.

[image]

Customers see low shipping rates and finish an order , then prices change and are angry. I would like show delivery options after cutromer register acc or save delivery address.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this script inside `$(document).ready(function(){` in file `/themes/[your_theme]/js/order-opc.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('.address_address1').length == 0) {
        $('#opc_delivery_methods').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#opc_delivery_methods').show();
    }
    [...]
```

Comment: And how it should work? Class `.address_address1` doesn't exist.